# Running two loops in R for mathematical expression calculation

Tags: r

I am trying to write the R code for the expression given in the image for calculation purposes. I tried to use two loops and `sapply` function but I failed. Can anyone suggest a suitable code for the calculation of this expression?

[image]

I tried below lines given in the image.

R Code tried:

[image: R Code tried]

Comment: You should show us what you tried

Comment: "I tried to use two loops and sapply function but i failed". Can you post that in your question and explain which part specifically and how it didn't work?

Comment: I have added the tried R code in the image.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  This community has a few rules [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [norms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and following them will help you get a good answer to your question.

Comment: In addition, you might want to review [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to provide an MCVE (a minimum, complete, and verifiable example). There's also [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4573108) that offers guidance for R-specific MCVEs.  Finally, it's best to avoid using images of code/data and [here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 1):

Please see as below:

```
gamma <- 1.5
s <- 1
k <- 3
i <- s:k
j <- lapply(i, function(x) 0:x)

prod_i <- sapply(j, function(x) prod(k + gamma - x))
f <- sum(factorial(k) / factorial(k - i) * prod_i)
f
# [1] 637.875
```

Comment: Perfect!! this is what, I was interested in. Thanks a lot!